# Whatever happened to "what ever" and whenever did it happen?

Tags: etymology, questions

I am curious to know when *whatever*, *whenever*, *wherever* and *whoever* first started being used as interrogative words. Merriam-Webster, etymonline and dictionary.com offer no hints. Wikipedia doesn't even mention them as interrogatives, completely ignoring the fact that there are countless books titled *Whatever happened to X?*. TheFreeDictionary.com points out that

> [c]ritics have occasionally objected to the one-word form, but many respected writers have used it

and leaves it at that (well, thanks for nothing).

Comment: "Whatever happened to “what ever” and whenever did it happen?" doesn't make sense to me. "Whatever happened to RegDwight?" = "Where is RegDwight nowadays?" "Whenever" usually isn't used as a question word, it's used in positive sentences: "Come whenever you like".

Comment: The NOAD reports that in the interrogative sense (_What ever was Mary thinking?_) the emphasis is on _ever_, and it should be spelled as the two words (_what ever_) because _ever_ is serving as an intensifier to the pronoun _what_.

Comment: @Shinto: I don't normally use any of the one-word forms myself, either, but that doesn't mean that others don't. Random House Dictionary: "whenever [...] 2. when? (used emphatically): *Whenever did he say that*?" Collins English Dictionary: "whenever [...] 4. an intensive form of *when*, used in questions: *whenever did he escape*?" My question is, how far this usage can be traced back, not whether it makes sense to you, myself, or anyone else.

Comment: you are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [OED's online entry](http://dictionary.oed.com/cgi/entry/50284130?single=1&query_type=word&queryword=whatever&first=1&max_to_show=10) on the interrogative form of *whatever*, the earliest entry for the pronoun usage as a single word is from 13—:

> 13.. Seuyn Sag. (W.) 3514 Son, what may al this noys be,..**Whateuer** sal it sygnyfy?

Interestingly, their first listed example of the two-word version is from 14—.

The first pronoun usage they have in the modern spelling:

> 1823 Spirit Publ. Jrnls. 409 **Whatever** possessed her, I know no more than the child unborn.

For the adjectival usage, the first example is in the two-word form.

> c1375 Cursor M. 321 (Fairf.) **Quat euer** e haly gaste wille, e fader and sone wil tyte fulfil.

The first instance of the single-word form appears in 1456,

> 1456 SIR G. HAYE Law Arms (S.T.S.) 228 **Quhatever** sik men dois, it is comperit to the dede of a beste.

and, with the spelling moving through Shakespeare's contraction *whatere* and Milton's more descriptive *Whate're* (notice the apostrophe), we see the first modern-spelling usage in Swift's *Gulliver's Travels*.

> 1726 SWIFT Gulliver IV. v, It is a Maxim among these Men, That **whatever** has been done before may legally be done again.

Whatever happened to "what ever" appears to have started happening a long while ago.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.etymonline.com also doesn't give much explanation besides giving a general century of the first use. However, it does mention that *whatever* is a variant of *whatsoever* as well as a construction of *what* and *ever*.

Comment: It's possible that "whatsoever" was related to "whatever" at some time in the past, but "Whatsoever" in modern usage has a very different meaning from "whatever".

Comment: The NOAD reports as archaic the use of _whatsoever_ as adjective and pronoun; in that case, it reports _whatsoever_ means _whatever_.